# Unable to get web-socket data in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket, socket.io

I have to get real time data and I am using websocket in angular-7 for this, but I didn't getting any data.

I used this reference https://dzone.com/articles/high-performance-angular-grid-with-web-sockets to achieve this. But not sure where I am wrong, So I am looking for some help here.

If any other solution then I am ready to use that too, I just have to get real-time data from "ws://stocks.mnet.website/"

**app.service.ts**

```
  socket: Socket;
  observer: Observer<any>;

  constructor() { }

  getQuotes(): Observable<any> {
    this.socket = socketIo('ws://stocks.mnet.website/',{transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket']});
    this.socket.on('data', (res) => {
        this.observer.next(res.data);
    });
    return this.createObservable();
  }
  createObservable(): Observable<any> {
      return new Observable<any>(observer => {
          this.observer = observer;
      });
  }
  private handleError(error) {
      console.error('server error:', error);
      if (error.error instanceof Error) {
          let errMessage = error.error.message;
          return Observable.throw(errMessage);
      }
      return Observable.throw(error || 'Socket.io server error');
  }
```

Comment: Here is a good tutorial using Sock.js and STOMP to implement websockets in angular.

https://g00glen00b.be/websockets-angular/

Comment: When I try to connect to ws://stocks.mnet.website/ using the test-page https://www.websocket.org/echo.html, nothing happens. Are you sure that the ws-endpoint is okay?

Comment: Yes, It's working fine with an other project developed in react.